# SQL(postgresql) запрос на создание таблицы с полем даты (YYYY-MM-DD-HH)

Tags: sql, postgresql, дата

подскажите пожалуйста команду для создания таблицы где будет поле с датой и временем типа YYYY-MM-DD-HH. Не очень понимаю какой тип данных использовать.

Например для таблицы "Test" где будут только поля "id" и "date", запрос будет выглядеть как

`create table Test(
'id' int not null,
'date' ???? not null
);`

что ставить на место "????" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PostgreSQL` для хранения времени предоставляет [типы данных](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html):

- `timestamp` с точностью до микросекунд
- `date` с точностью в день
- `time` для времени без даты

Как можно заметить, для хранения только даты и часа встроенного формата нет. Предложить можно на выбор следующие подходы:

### timestamp

Использовать timestamp как есть. Несложно добавить небольшое ограничение, чтобы случайно не писать значения не укладывающиеся в заданную точность:

```
create temp table dt (
  t timestamp check ((date_trunc('hour',t) = t))
);
```

Добавленный `check constraint` эффективно запретит попытки писать в поле что-то вроде `2019-04-06 21:56:53`, но разрешит `2019-01-01 23:00:00`

### Два поля

Очевидное решение - сделать поле типа даты и отдельное поле для хранения часа

```
create temp table dt2 (
    d date,
    h smallint check (h >=0 and h <=23)
);
```

Вариацией этого случая будет определение и использование [составного типа данных](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html).

### Собственный тип данных

[Возможностей расширения](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend.html) Postgresql достаточно для добавления собственного типа данных. Впрочем, это заметно сложнее, а так же может угрожать стабильности вашей базы из-за ошибок в реализации нового типа и множества вспомогательных операций вроде поддержки статистики и функций сравнения. Вряд ли целесообразно подробно описывать.

Comment: ого, спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 1):

Postgresql использует следующие типы даты/времени:

- **timestamp** (**with time zone** / **without time zone**) - с часовым поясом и без оного. without по умолчанию
- **date** - без часового пояса
- **time** - время без даты
- **interval** - интервал времени

Запрос с датой без локали будет выглядеть примерно вот так:

```
create table Test(
'id' int not null,
'date' timestamp not null
);
```

Comment: спасибо, буду пользоваться)